# How to sort items with local characters using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, character

I want to sort the above divs alphabetically and have this code:

```js
$('#btnabc').click(function(){
  $('.item').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {return -1;}
    else {return 1;}
  }).appendTo('#panelb');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='panelb'>
  <div class='item'>zaba</div>
  <div class='item'>žaba</div>
  <div class='item'>ciao</div>
  <div class='item'>ćao</div>
  <div class='item'>suma</div>
  <div class='item'>šuma</div>
</div>
```

It works, but items with local characters are not sorted properly. 
Basically, during the sort proccess I need:

```
`ž` - to be considered as - `z`
`ć` and `č` - to be considered as - `c`
`š` - to be considered as - `s`
`đ` - to be considered as - `d`
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four things:

1. Your code always returns -1 or 1. Sometimes it should return 0, e.g., when the items are the same.
2. Use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to get a locale-sensitive comparison.
3. Officially, jQuery doesn't *have* a `sort` method, so using it is a bad idea (as is using undocumented methods in general). Use `Array#sort` instead.
4. `textContent` isn't cross-browser reliable. Since you're using jQuery already, I'd use `$(a).text()` rather than `a.textContent`.

So:

```
var items = $('.item').get();
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
});
$('#panelb').append(items);
```

(That can be written as a single statement, but I used three for clarity.)

Example:

```js
$('#btnabc').click(function(){
    var items = $('.item').get();
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    });
    $('#panelb').append(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='panelb'>
<div class='item'>zaba</div>
<div class='item'>žaba</div>
<div class='item'>ciao</div>
<div class='item'>ćao</div>
<div class='item'>suma</div>
<div class='item'>šuma</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnabc" value="Click me">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.